# How to add simultaneously moving touches in Appium iOS if one's duration is longer?

Tags: appium, appium-ios, xcuitest, python-appium

There's a `UIView` in my app. It receives `UITouch`-es, and has quite complex logic for their processing. The processing logic depends on UIKit touch interface.

I don't know how to reproduce such case neither with `TouchAction`, nor with `MultiAction`. 
There're 2 touches. **touch2** starts later, and lasts shorter:
[image]

In the moments `t3` and `t4` touches move simultaneously, then the **touch2** ends, but **touch1** still moves. 
My current not-working code: https://gist.github.com/gatamar/c7182292a1b54379cc26f3e38c823199

In UIKit, touch events look like this:

```
touchesBegan: [touch1_t1]
touchesBegan: [touch2_t2]
touchesMoved: [touch1_t3, touch2_t3]
touchesMoved: [touch1_t4, touch2_t4]
touchesEnded: [touch2_t4]
touchesMoved: [touch1_t5]
touchesEnded: [touch1_t5]
```

Is it possible to achieve this with Appium?

Can `MultiAction` perform two non-simultaneous touches?

Is there in Python Appium Client more low-level API e.g. Selenium, XCUITest?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i would recommend you trying to use gestures instead of MultiTouch. i am able to provide you some examples only in Java. If you are interesting in it - let me know. Libraries to work with are: `PointerInput`, `Sequence`. Dont know about relevant python libraries

Comment: @Vault23 Do you mean Sequence from `import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Sequence`?

Comment: @Vault23 Yes, I am interested also in Java solutions. :) It would be great if you gave some links to the libraries and example code.

Comment: @OlhaPavliuk I am also stuck with a similar problem while writing tests for my application. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Vishwas I'm so sorry, I've postponed working on this because priorities changed. While my current assumption is that this API is implemented in Java Appium Client, not in Python, if implemented at all.

Comment: @Vishwas I'm talking about advice from Vault23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey then. here is an example of using gestures in Java.

```
PointerInput finger = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "finger");
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
//get your screen size
Point source = new Point(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
//this is resolution of your screen 
Sequence pinch = new Sequence(finger, 0);
pinch.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(0),
                PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), source.x / 2, source.y / 2));
pinch.addAction(finger.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
pinch.addAction(new Pause(finger, Duration.ofMillis(100)));
pinch.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(600),
                    PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), source.x / 3, source.y / 3));
```

and then you need to `perform` that sequense by calling 
`driver.perform(Arrays.asList(pinchAndZoom1));`
As you can see, you might modify duration of gesture, play around it and you will understand how it works. Also [here](https://appiumpro.com/editions/29) is some docs with examples.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at it.